# std::move on const char* with perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I have an interesting issue on the `MSVC v19.28` compiler (later versions fix this problem) where a `const char*` being passed to a variadic template *class* fails to resolve correctly. If the `const char*` is passed to a variadic template *function* then there are no errors.

Here's the code for clarity:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... T_Args>
struct Foo
{
    template <typename T_Func>
    void foo(T_Func func, T_Args&&... args)
    {
        func(std::forward<T_Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename T_Func, typename... T_Args>
void bar(T_Func func, T_Args&&... args)
{
    func(std::forward<T_Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    bar([](int, float, const char* c){ }, 5, 5.0f, "Hello world");

    // <source>(26): error C2672: 'Foo<int,float,const char *>::foo': no matching overloaded function found
    // <source>(26): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [12]' to 'const char *&&'
    // <source>(26): note: You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
    Foo<int, float, const char*> f;
    f.foo([](int, float, const char* c){ }, 5, 5.0f, "Hello world");

    // this compiles, but what are the repurcussions of std::move() on a string literal?
    Foo<int, float, const char*> g;
    g.foo([](int, float, const char* c){ }, 5, 5.0f, std::move("Hello world"));
}
```

Since I work on a large team, I am unable to recommend upgrading the toolchain/compiler and so I am looking for workarounds until the compiler can be updated.

One of the workaround is to use `std::move("Hello world")`. What is `std::move` doing do a `const char*` and what the potential side-effects?

Comment: Another workaround: `+"Hello world"` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WeWM4fzEn).

Comment: Do you really want r-value references (as fixed by the class, there are not forwarding references).

Comment: N.b. You aren't calling `bar<lambda, int, float, const char *>`, you are calling `bar<lambda, int, float, const char(&)[12]>`

Comment: @Caleth right - I did not fully understand why `const char(&)[12]` cannot decay to `const char*` - but I understand why the parameter pack is not deduced on the member function call, which was an oversight on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is `std::move` doing to a `const char [12]` and what are the potential side-effects?

The ordinary array-to-pointer implicit conversion, and none. Pointer types don't have move constructors or move assignment operators, so "moves" are copies (of the pointer the array decayed to).

Aside: I don't think your template does what you think it does. The pack `T_Args...` isn't deduced in when calling `Foo::foo`, so you don't have a universal reference, instead it's rvalue references.

Did you mean something like

```
template <typename... T_Args>
struct Foo
{
    template <typename T_Func, typename... T_Args2>
    void foo(T_Func func, T_Args2&&... args)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<T_Args, T_Args2> && ..., "Arguments must match parameters");
        func(std::forward<T_Args2>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Or possibly the even simpler

```
struct Foo
{
    template <typename T_Func, typename... T_Args>
    void foo(T_Func func, T_Args&&... args)
    {
        func(std::forward<T_Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Comment: *"so "moves" are copies"*. but just the pointer, not the whole array :)

Comment: this works great (+1) except for when we are dealing with `const char*`, `is_assignable` or `is_convertible` both fail - I guess that would be another question altogether : https://godbolt.org/z/coqnMKTcs

Comment: @Samaursa `is_constructible` is probably more correct here anyway

Answer (score 2):

It's MSVC bug.
See [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-fails-to-compile-correct-example-of/1359579?space=62&q=%5BVisual%20Studio%202019%20version%2016.9%5D%20C2440&stateGroup=closed&ftype=problem&sort=votes), which is a [Visual Studio 2019 16.9 Bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=62&q=%5BVisual%20Studio%202019%20version%2016.9%5D%20C2440&stateGroup=closed&ftype=problem&sort=votes)(Resolved).
Visual Studio 2019 16.9 uses `MSVC v19.28` ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering)).

If your intend is to use perfect forwarding using universal reference, move the `...T_Args` from the class to the function as the other answer said.

But if your intend is to restrict the parameter type when declaring a class, you can write something like below.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename ...Args>
struct Foo {
  template<typename F, typename ...Args2>
  std::enable_if_t<(std::is_convertible_v<Args2, Args> && ...)>
  foo(F func, Args2&&... args)
  {
    func(std::forward<Args2>(args)...);
  }
};


int main() {

  Foo<int, float, const char*> f;
  f.foo([](int, float, const char* c){ }, 5, 5.0f, "Hello world");
  
  // invalid type!
  //f.foo([](int, float, const char* c){ }, 5, "", "Hello world");

  return 0;
}
```

Works in MSVC 19.28 [link](https://godbolt.org/z/c8jPvxGd8)

Or maybe just use `std::is_invocable`.